# How to print a space between each word in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I remember seeing a function on w3school where you can print out all the words of an array and add a space between them, But no matter how much I google I can't find it.

Example of how it could look:

```js
    function printWords() {
      var array = ["Car", "Bus", "Motorcykle"];
      print(array.addSpaces());
    }
```

Comment: `.join(" ");` ...

Comment: Instead of just taking a wild stab and making a function name up out of thin air, your first step should be to [visit MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) and become enlightened.

Comment: It was an example to show kindof how I expected it to work @tadman

Comment: I know what your intention is, but I'm saying it's a very inefficient way to solve problems. MDN has some fantastic documentation that will more often than not explain what you can and can't do with core JavaScript.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join). You can specify a character to put between the values, in your case:

```
array.join(' ');
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, really helpful!

Answer (score 8):

ASDFGerte has exactly the answer:

```
function printWords() {
  var array = ["Car", "Bus", "Motorcykle"];
  print(array.join(" "));
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

Comment: The w3schools link here is problematic. That site is highly toxic and should be avoided whenever possible. The MDN version of same is significantly better and is basically the de-facto documentation on JavaScript.

Comment: @tadman I have never heard that before.  Why is that site bad?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I'll replace with less toxic link.

Comment: It's full of out of date advice, obsolete documentation, and heaps of dangerous practices, especially when it comes to databases. The whole thing is a cancer on the development community.

Comment: Also, if you take someone else's answer from a comment, I'd check off the "Community Wiki" box on your answer, just to be nice.

Comment: Thanks for the fix. It's a little thing, but anything that helps someone fall victim to w3schools is a good thing.

Comment: @davidxxx Boundless amounts of bad advice. They've cleaned up their CSS section lately but the MySQL+PHP stuff is apocalyptically bad.

Comment: While I will _always_ go to MDN first, that stand on w3schools is so out of date that even http://www.w3fools.com/ has been updated.

Comment: @tadman ah  Ok. I sometimes used their JavaScript examples. It helped me often. The examples are ready to use. Now I am not an JS "expert". So maybe best practices are not always shown.

Comment: @davidxxx The MDN site should be the first place you go, but if it doesn't give enough detail, or the right sort of examples, sites like w3schools *might* help. The problem is people go there first, get false impressions, and then never learn the right way to do things, using techniques often decades out of date as if they're a best practice.

Comment: @tadman On this point, you are totally right. MDN is the reference. As I think about it, most of examples I used from w3schools refer to third party libraries such as Angular or Bootstrap. Anyway, thank you for your feedback. I will remember that.

Answer (score 2):

You can store the contents of the array with the spaces in between, in the new variable array_content as described below, by consecutively iterating and storing each item of the array with the space in between.

```js
function printWords() {
  var array = ["Car ", "Bus ", "Motorcykle "];
  var res = ' ';
  var array_content = '';
  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    array_content = array_content + array[i] + res;

  console.log(array_content);
}
printWords();
```