# Is there a way to separate this JSON data without mapping for this case?

Tags: reactjs

Is there any way to separate out the data that will display from `{pokemon.abilities}`, or is mapping over it the only way?

I have omitted some of the code in-between since it doesn't pertain to the question.

Here is how it displays and I would like to have space between the two words obviously.

[image]

```
const PokemonDetail = ({ match }) => {


    const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState({
        types: [],
        egg_groups: [],
        abilities: [],
        stats: {}
    });



                <h3 className="seperator"> Profile </h3>
                <h4>Height: {pokemon.height} m</h4>
                <h4>Weight: {pokemon.weight} kg</h4>
                <h4>Abilites: {pokemon.abilities} </h4>
                <h4>Egg Groups: {pokemon.egg_groups}</h4>
```

Comment: Updated Question with image of how it displays.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print a space between each word in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46855927/how-to-print-a-space-between-each-word-in-an-array)

Comment: In fact, it was. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This just separates the items with a space. Simple enough :)

pokemon.abilities.join(" ")